# How to flip the trigonometric circle around the 45° angle?

Tags: function, math, rotation, trigonometry, angle

I am looking for a mathematical function capable of flipping the trigonometric circle around the "axis" located on the 45° vector (or pi/4 radians).

Such as :

```
|---------|---------|
|   x     |   f(x)  |
|---------|---------|
|   0     |   90    |
|   45    |   45    |
|   90    |   0     |
|   135   |   315   |
|   180   |   270   |
|   225   |   225   |
|   270   |   180   |
|   315   |   135   |
|---------|---------|
```

Just to give a few examples.

So basically I need to turn a compass rose :

[image: Compass rose]

into a trigonometric circle :

[image]

I only found things like "180 - angle" but that is not the kind of rotation I'm looking for.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you flip a circle around any vector that passes through the centre point, you get the same circle, surely.

Comment: The same circle, yes, but flipped, so that the 45° and the 225° marks stay in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difficulty in your problem is the "jump" in the result, where `f(90)` should be `0` but `f(91)` should be `359`. A solution is to use a jumpy operator--namely, the modulus operator, which is often represented by the `%` character.

In a language like Python, where the modulus operator always returns a positive result, you could use

```
def f(x):
    return (90 - x) % 360
```

Some languages can return a negative result if the number before the operator is negative. You can treat that by adding `360` before taking the modulus, and this should work in all languages with a modulus operator:

```
def f(x):
    return (450 - x) % 360
```

You can demonstrate either function with:

```
for a in range(0, 360, 45):
    print(a, f(a))
```

which prints what was desired:

```
0 90
45 45
90 0
135 315
180 270
225 225
270 180
315 135
```

If your language does not have the modulus operator, it can be simulated by using the `floor` or `int` function. Let me know if you need a solution using either of those instead of modulus.

Comment: (450 - x) % 360 is the solution I was looking for. Thank you so much!